# Xcode Derived Data to /dev/null

Tags: xcode, developer-tools

Anyone who's worked with Xcode knows how finicky it can be regarding build settings, linker errors, and other generalized nonsense. Add in any dependency manager like CocoaPods, and all of a sudden you're deleting derived data nearly every time you build.

So my question is two-fold:

**What exactly is Derived Data responsible for?**

and

**What would happen if I just dropped its use entirely, by redirecting to `/dev/null`?**
[image: DerivedDataDevNull]

Answer (score 3):

The `DerivedData` folder contains all the data, well, derived from Xcode processing. This includes any build artifacts such as header maps, intermediate build steps (`.o` files and such), and built products (compiled code). It is the destination for any and all build logs, run logs, and test results. Finally, it contains any indexing caches used for code coloring and searching.

Basically, it'd break everything. Doing exactly what you say with `/dev/null` and building causes an extremely large number of issues, mainly because it is actually trying to read and write files there and can't.

Hypothetically, if it could exist without DerivedData or anything resembling it (Xcode used to heavily rely on a `Build/` folder, for instance), compilation would be impossibly slow and memory hungry.

Strange behavior in Xcode related to the `DerivedData`, and issues fixed by the clearing of such, are mostly because cache invalidation is really hard. Like, really difficult.

Comment: Bless you, @zwaldowski